# Select all, depending checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have following functionality for "select all checkboxes" and "depending checkboxes", but it is not working as I want.
1. if I select "select all" the "controlled" checkboxes will stay disabled 
2. when enable "controlled" checkbox using "controller" and than use "select all" the "controlled" chackboxes stay active. I need them to be inactive when they are not selected.

I tried to create if statement (commented) to solve this, but it is not working as expected. Is there some other solution or it will be maybe better to reset checkboxes after unselect "select all" checkbox? In case of reseting I need to reset only group of checkboxes, not the whole form.

```
    $('form').ready(function() {
    var $check1 = $('input[id*=selectAll]'),
        $check2 = $('tr th :checkbox'),
        $checkAll = $check1.add($check2);
    $checkAll.on('click keydown', function () {
        var checkedStatus = this.checked,
            $selected1 = $(this).closest(".formFieldWrapper").find('input:checkbox:not(:first):not([data-leader])'),
            $selected2 = $(this).closest("table").find('tr td :checkbox'),
            $selectedAll = $selected1.add($selected2);
            $selectedAll.each(function () {

           // if($checkAll.prop('checked', true)) {
            $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus)  //.prop('disabled', false)
           // } else {
           // $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus);
           // $checkAll.prop('checked', false);
           // $('.controlled').prop('disabled', true)
           // }   

        });
        $selectedAll.on('click keydown', function(){
        $checkAll.prop('checked', false) 
        });
    });
});

$('.controlled').prop('disabled', true);
$('.controller').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $inputs = $($this.data('target'));
    $inputs.prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    if (!this.checked) {
        $inputs.prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZE6n/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
 var $check1 = $('input[id*=selectAll]'),
        $check2 = $('tr th :checkbox'),
        $checkAll = $check1.add($check2);

    $checkAll.on('click keydown', function () {
        var checkedStatus = this.checked,
            $selected1 = $(this).closest(".formFieldWrapper").find('input:checkbox:not(:first):not([data-leader])'),
            $selected2 = $(this).closest("table").find('tr td :checkbox'),
            $selectedAll = $selected1.add($selected2);

        $selectedAll.each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus);

            if (checkedStatus === true) {
                $('.controlled').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $('.controlled').prop('disabled', true);
            }

        });

        $selectedAll.on('click keydown', function () {
            $checkAll.prop('checked', false)
        });
    });


$('.controlled').prop('disabled', true);
$('.controller').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $inputs = $($this.data('target'));

    $inputs.prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    if (!this.checked) {
        $inputs.prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```